# Custom Lightning / Aura Component not rendering a dynamic list unless manually refresh page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-design-system

Hey so I have a custom Aura / lightning component on the Quote object pages. The component basically as a user search bar that searches for users. It's built basically using this lightning design system,

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/#Option(s)-Selected

When I login and go to a quote record and search for a user the above functionality in the link works fine. The problem is when I go to another quote record and search the drop-down list doesn't 'render' even though the data is coming. I have debugged and printed it in the console. The data is comming from my controller. But the drop-down search result doesn't render. If I refresh the page manually and search again the search dropdown renders.

Any ideas of how to make it work on any quote page correctly ? Do I have to refresh or update something ?
I tried $A. get('e. force:refreshView'). fire(); but it didn't work. It behaves the same. It works for the first quote record I open correctly. But, then when I go to a different quote the drop-down search result doesn't render. It will render If I refresh the page and search again.

Edit: Code Added

```
<div class="slds-form-element" style="width:95%;">

    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">Additional Users to CC / BCC:</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        
        <div class="slds-combobox_container">
            <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                
                <!-- User Search Bar -->
                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                    <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-id-1" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-1" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..." onfocus="{!c.handleUserSearch}" onkeyup="{!c.handleUserSearch}" />
                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right"></span>
                </div>
                
                <!-- User Search Result Dropdown -->
                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--Selected Users List-->
        <div class="slds-listbox_selection-group" style="height : auto;">
            <ul id="selected-user-list" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_horizontal" role="listbox" aria-label="Selected Options:" aria-orientation="horizontal"></ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Controller (JS):

```
handleUserSearch : function (component, event, helper) {
        
        console.log('handleUserSearch');

        let getUsersByKeywordAction = component.get('c.getUsersByKeyword');
        console.log(getUsersByKeywordAction);

        getUsersByKeywordAction.setParams({
            searchInput: event.target.value
        });

        getUsersByKeywordAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
            
            let state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);

            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){

                let userList = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log(userList);

                if(userList){

                    let resultListBox = document.getElementById('listbox-id-1');
                    
                    if(resultListBox){

                        resultListBox.innerHTML = '';

                        let unorderListElement = document.createElement('ul');
                        unorderListElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical');
                        unorderListElement.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');

                        for(let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++){

                            let listElement = document.createElement('li');
                            let listDivElement = document.createElement('div');
                            let listDivSpanMediaFigureElement = document.createElement('span');
                            let listDivSpanMediaFigureIconElement = document.createElement('span');
                            let listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                            let listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgPathElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
                            let listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "ellipse");
                            let listDivSpanMediaBodyElement = document.createElement('span');
                            let listDivSpanMediaBodyUserNameElement = document.createElement('span');
                            let listDivSpanMediaBodyUserEmailElement = document.createElement('span');

                            listElement.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');
                            listElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-listbox__item');

                            listDivElement.setAttribute('id', 'option' + (i + 1));
                            listDivElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta');
                            listDivElement.setAttribute('role', 'option');

                            listDivElement.addEventListener('click', function(){

                                let userListContainer = document.getElementById('selected-user-list');
                                let selectedUserDetails = this.children[1].children;
                                let iSUserAlreadySelected = false;

                                if(selectedUserDetails && userListContainer){

                                    for(let i = 0; i < userListContainer.children.length; i++){
                                        
                                        let userEmail = userListContainer.children[i].children[0].children[1].innerText;
                                        if(selectedUserDetails[1].innerText === userEmail){
                                            iSUserAlreadySelected = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if(iSUserAlreadySelected === false){

                                        let userlistElement = document.createElement('li');
                                        let mainSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
                                        let iconSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
                                        let iconSpanSvgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                                        let iconSpanSvgPathElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
                                        let iconSpanSvgEllipseElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "ellipse");
                                        let iconAssistiveTextSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
                                        let labelSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
                                        let removeSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
                                        let removeSpanSvgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                                        let removeSpanSvgPathElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

                                        userlistElement.setAttribute('class','slds-listbox-item');
                                        userlistElement.setAttribute('role','presentation');

                                        mainSpanElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-pill');
                                        mainSpanElement.setAttribute('role', 'option');
                                        mainSpanElement.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');

                                        iconSpanElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-user slds-pill__icon_container');
                                        iconSpanElement.setAttribute('title', selectedUserDetails[0].innerText);

                                        iconSpanSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 100 100');
                                        iconSpanSvgElement.setAttribute('id', 'user');

                                        iconSpanSvgPathElement.setAttribute('d' , 'M80 71.2V74c0 3.3-2.7 6-6 6H26c-3.3 0-6-2.7-6-6v-2.8c0-7.3 8.5-11.7 16.5-15.2.3-.1.5-.2.8-.4.6-.3 1.3-.3 1.9.1C42.4 57.8 46.1 59 50 59c3.9 0 7.6-1.2 10.8-3.2.6-.4 1.3-.4 1.9-.1.3.1.5.2.8.4 8 3.4 16.5 7.8 16.5 15.1z');

                                        iconSpanSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('cx', '50');
                                        iconSpanSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('cy', '36.5');
                                        iconSpanSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('rx', '14.9');
                                        iconSpanSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('ry', '16.5');

                                        iconSpanSvgElement.appendChild(iconSpanSvgPathElement);
                                        iconSpanSvgElement.appendChild(iconSpanSvgEllipseElement);

                                        iconSpanElement.appendChild(iconSpanSvgElement);

                                        iconAssistiveTextSpanElement.setAttribute('class' , 'slds-assistive-text');
                                        iconAssistiveTextSpanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedUserDetails[0].innerText));

                                        iconSpanElement.appendChild(iconAssistiveTextSpanElement);

                                        labelSpanElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-pill__label');
                                        labelSpanElement.setAttribute('title', selectedUserDetails[0].innerText);
                                        //labelSpanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedUserDetails[0].innerText));
                                        labelSpanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedUserDetails[1].innerText));

                                        removeSpanElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-icon_container slds-pill__remove');
                                        removeSpanElement.setAttribute('title', 'Remove');
                                        removeSpanElement.setAttribute('style', 'cursor : pointer;');

                                        removeSpanElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                            this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                                        });

                                        removeSpanSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 52 52');
                                        removeSpanSvgElement.setAttribute('id', 'close');

                                        removeSpanSvgPathElement.setAttribute('d' , 'M31 25.4l13-13.1c.6-.6.6-1.5 0-2.1l-2-2.1c-.6-.6-1.5-.6-2.1 0L26.8 21.2c-.4.4-1 .4-1.4 0L12.3 8c-.6-.6-1.5-.6-2.1 0l-2.1 2.1c-.6.6-.6 1.5 0 2.1l13.1 13.1c.4.4.4 1 0 1.4L8 39.9c-.6.6-.6 1.5 0 2.1l2.1 2.1c.6.6 1.5.6 2.1 0L25.3 31c.4-.4 1-.4 1.4 0l13.1 13.1c.6.6 1.5.6 2.1 0L44 42c.6-.6.6-1.5 0-2.1L31 26.8c-.4-.4-.4-1 0-1.4z');
                                        removeSpanSvgElement.appendChild(removeSpanSvgPathElement);

                                        removeSpanElement.appendChild(removeSpanSvgElement);

                                        mainSpanElement.appendChild(iconSpanElement);
                                        mainSpanElement.appendChild(labelSpanElement);
                                        mainSpanElement.appendChild(removeSpanElement);

                                        userlistElement.appendChild(mainSpanElement);

                                        userListContainer.appendChild(userlistElement);

                                        document.getElementById('combobox-id-1').value = '';
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        console.log('User alread Selected !');
                                    }

                                }

                                document.getElementById('listbox-id-1').parentElement.classList.value = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
                                
                            });

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-user');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconElement.setAttribute('style', 'width : 100%;');

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 100 100');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement.setAttribute('id', 'user');

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgPathElement.setAttribute('d', 'M80 71.2V74c0 3.3-2.7 6-6 6H26c-3.3 0-6-2.7-6-6v-2.8c0-7.3 8.5-11.7 16.5-15.2.3-.1.5-.2.8-.4.6-.3 1.3-.3 1.9.1C42.4 57.8 46.1 59 50 59c3.9 0 7.6-1.2 10.8-3.2.6-.4 1.3-.4 1.9-.1.3.1.5.2.8.4 8 3.4 16.5 7.8 16.5 15.1z');

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('cx', '50');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('cy', '36.5');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('rx', '14.9');
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement.setAttribute('ry', '16.5');
                            
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgPathElement);
                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgEllipseElement);

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureIconElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaFigureIconSvgElement);

                            listDivSpanMediaFigureElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaFigureIconElement);

                            listDivSpanMediaBodyElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-media__body');
                            
                            listDivSpanMediaBodyUserNameElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity');
                            listDivSpanMediaBodyUserNameElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userList[i].Name));

                            listDivSpanMediaBodyUserEmailElement.setAttribute('class', 'slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity');
                            listDivSpanMediaBodyUserEmailElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userList[i].Email));

                            listDivSpanMediaBodyElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaBodyUserNameElement);
                            listDivSpanMediaBodyElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaBodyUserEmailElement);

                            listDivElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaFigureElement);
                            listDivElement.appendChild(listDivSpanMediaBodyElement);


                            listElement.appendChild(listDivElement);

                            unorderListElement.appendChild(listElement);
                        }

                        resultListBox.appendChild(unorderListElement);

                        if(userList.length > 0){
                            event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.value = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.value + ' slds-is-open';
                        }
                        else{
                            event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.value = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.value = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log(response.getErrors());
                //event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.value = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(getUsersByKeywordAction);

        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    
    },
```

Controller (Apex):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<User> getUsersByKeyword(String searchInput) {
    
    String searchKeyword = '';
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    
    if(searchInput != null && searchInput != ''){
        searchKeyword = '%' + searchInput + '%';
        userList = Database.query('SELECT id, name, email from User WHERE name LIKE :searchKeyword');
    }

    return userList;
}
```

Comment: you have to share the code so that we can help, if i have to guess you have to put change handler on the list attribute and reinitialize the component when it changes

Comment: *change handler on recordId since i guess you are going on different record

Comment: Is there any reason for the fairly non-standard Aura syntax? If you used some repeat elements and made it data driven, you would probably have more luck.